# Breaking Inheritance Chain

Tags: c#, oop

Recently I have been asked in an Interview that: *"Can you give an example of a situation where is it necessary to break the Inheritance chain?"*. I am not very sure if I could follow the question exactly.

Does any such situation exist when we to break the inheritance chain?

I tried google, but didn't get any clues.

Comment: I guess if that situation **does exist**, we will be able to find it right **in .NET Framework library**.

Comment: My only guess is the "new" keyword which hides base implementations, rather than overrides them. Might this be what the question was talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/01/07/virtual-methods-and-brittle-base-classes.aspx) with a good explanation on why you'd want to "break the inheritance chain" (or "seal" your class).

Comment: Thanks for the link...seems that was the answer the interviewer was looking for.. :)

Comment: which would imply the better question is: Q. Do you read Eric Lippert's blog?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be exactly about 'breaking' the chain - unless you've done it too late!

Comment: Additionally, that post is talking about javascript. The premises still apply though.

Comment: You should at least summarize the blog post in the answer.  An answer that is simply a link to the answer is not a very good answer, as it not only forces the user to go look to see if it's useful, but the link could easily break over time.

Answer (score 6):

A. When we get stupid questions that make no sense.

Inheritance is just a tool for managing and re-using code. Composition is a strong tool that is not part of an "inheritance-chain" so I'm guessing that's an answer they're looking for?

Another possible answer they're looking for is utilizing interfaces. As interfaces don't require an "inheritance chain". They enable you to be a little more flexible with your architecture and step away from strict inheritance "chains".

However the question implies that you have a number of objects that all inherit from one another and for some reason you "break" the chain of inheritance somewhere. There is no "set" reason why you'd do this as each implementation of OOP that addresses a problem is typically unique.

The way the interviewer phrased the question makes little to no sense. It's a bad interview question that wont result in the best answers or necessarily tell you anything about a candidate except that they don't understand your madness either ;).

EDIT: added some "better" questions.

Better questions include:

> Q. What is the difference between inheritance and composition?
>   Q. I have the following class model (one crying out for an interface), can I improve it at all?
>   Q. I'm re-designing a base class and want to prevent other people from overriding this function. Can I do that?
>   Q. Is there a problem with calling virtual methods in class constructors, if so, what?

Comment: +1 "A. When we get stupid questions that make no sense."

Comment: @Quibblesome: You are right, that's the day for the interviewer to ask all no-sense questions :)